# Print prime numbers in an interval

Tags: java, primes

Here is my code.
I know it maybe very complicated with stupid errors but I am learning!
It always outputs only 2, whatever n is.

```
public static void prime(int n)
{
    int i;
    int b = 1;
    int d;
    int a =0;
    for (i=1; i!=n; i++){
        while (b!=i){
            d = i / b;
            if (d == i)
                a = 1;
            else
                a = 2;
            b++;
        }
        if (a==1)
            System.out.println( i);
    }
```

Comment: [**How To Determine A Prime Number In Java**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/)

Comment: To fix this by changing the least number of lines, I think what you could do is take `d = i % b`, and then set `a = 2` if `d == 0`.

Comment: Avoid using `!=` as the termination condition for numbers like that. This check highly depends on how you increment/decrement the variables. Therefore you can easily skip the situation there `i==n`. Use `<=` (or `<`) and `>=` (or `>`) for situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what your strange while loop has do to with finding if a number is prime.

You should be checking if `n` is divisible by any number `i` between `2` and `sqrt(n)`.

You check that with the condition `if (n%i==0)`.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number is prime, you should check if the number is divisible by 1 and itself. Here is a simple code snippet that does it.

```
public static void prime (int n){
int countZero=0; //counts the number of times n is divisible by another number
//@var div is the divisor
for (int div=1;div<=n;div++){
      if (n%div==0){
          countZero++; 
       }
      //n is divisible by 1 and itself
      if (countZero==2){ 
         System.out.println(n+", is a prime number");
}
```